# VB.net // how do you half round a number down?

Tags: vb.net

So for example I need to half the number 43 to an integer, however when I do this it rounds the 21.5 made to 22 when I want it to be rounded down to 21. How do I do this? I'm using VB.net

Comment: [Integer division operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator)

Comment: What do you want to happen with negative numbers? Should -43/2 be -21 or -22 ? Or will it never be negative?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Math.Truncate(43.0 / 2.0)`? This will divide by two, and then drop any fraction, leaving only the integer part of the division.

Comment: @Wheatley_boy - You are welcome and do not forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is 43 >> 1 (this is a logical right shift - the fastest method). 43 \ 2 (this is an integer divide - second fastest).

Comment: Compilers tend to be written to spot things like division by two and use faster methods if they are available, so it is usually better to write what you want to happen, not how you think it should be done. Not least because the former makes the code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Well rounding to 23 is correct... mathematically, however, if you want to round down:

Example: (WPF)

```
Dim a As Integer = 43
Dim b As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(a / 2))
Label1.Content = b
```

Example: (WinForms)

```
Dim a As Integer = 43
Dim b As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(a / 2))
Label1.Text= b
```